# Apache mod_rewrite problem with adding a query string on an internal rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

I need to replace `/xyz` with `/index.html?dh=xyz`. I use the following config in httpd.conf:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!dh"
RewriteRule "^/(.*)$" "/index.html?dh=$1" [R]
```

This works perfectly if [R] flag is present, but if I remove it, the query string is missing from the resulting URL. I would like to use the internal rewrite (no [R]). Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks as if it should work, although you'd probably want/need to use the `L` flag. Do you have any other directives (mod_rewrite, mod_alias)?

Comment: "the query string is missing from the resulting URL" - how / where are you reading the query string (URL parameters)?

Comment: I don't have any other rewrites or aliases, therefore I have no L flag. Here is the entire index.html: <script>
console.log(self.location);
</script>

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the entire index.html: `<script> console.log(self.location); </script>`

Well, that's the problem. You won't be able to see the rewritten URL (and query string) from client-side JavaScript.

An *internal rewrite* is entirely internal to the server. JavaScript only sees the initial URL of the request - the URL displayed in the browsers address bar. eg. `/xyz`.

Comment: If this answered your question, then please mark it as accepted (green tick on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote (click on "up arrow") answers that you find useful. Thanks.